# Will data saved in chrome.storage be synced if user switch to another computer with same google account?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Background:**

Hi everyone, I am developing a chrome extension in the form of new tab.
Now hyperlinks contained in the new tab page is fixed and I wanna make those links customizable.

**Progress**

I did some research in the internet and I found chrome.storage can provide data storage for pages. However, I am wondering if it can sync the data between multiple computers when the user logs in same google account?

Answer (score 1):

I just looked further into the chrome.storage API description. Luckily it provide data sync for user with same google account across different computers!
Thanks for this network again!

[chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

> Usage
>
> To store user data for your extension, you can use either storage.sync or storage.local. When using storage.sync, the stored data will automatically be synced to any Chrome browser that the user is logged into, provided the user has sync enabled.

It's hard to find any useful information in Chinese when I am facing a problem, sof is splendid.